# How can I validate fields in a table in Vaadin with Scala

Tags: scala, validation, vaadin

How can I validate a field in a vaadin table? For example the year field with a regex:

```
   val persons: BeanContainer[Int, Person] =
   new BeanContainer[Int, Person] classOf[Person])

   persons.setBeanIdProperty("id")
   persons.addBean(new Person("Thomas", "Mann", 1929, 123123))
   persons.addBean(new Person("W. B.", "Yeats", 1923, 643454))
   persons.addBean(new Person("Günter", "Grass", 1999, 743523))

   // create table
   val table: Table = new Table("Nobel Prize for Literature", persons)

   table.setVisibleColumns(Array("id", "firstName", "lastName", "year"))

   table.setColumnHeader("lastName", "last name")
   table.setColumnHeader("firstName", "first name")
   table.setColumnHeader("year", "year")

   // create a validator 
   val yearValidator = new RegexpValidator("[1-2][0-9]{3}", 
                                       "year must be a number 1000-2999.");

   // TODO check the year field!
   table.addValidator(yearValidator)
```

I create a Regex Validator, but how can I set the validator to the right field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to intercept the creation of the fields with a field factory and add the validators there:

```
    table.setTableFieldFactory(new DefaultFieldFactory() {
        @Override
        public Field createField(Item item, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
            Field field = super.createField(item, propertyId, uiContext);
            if ("year".equals(propertyId)) {
                field.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("[1-2][0-9]{3}", 
                                   "year must be a number 1000-2999.");
            }
            return field;
        }
    });
```

(Java, not Scala, but it should be straightforward to translate this to scala).

Comment: More info about validate table fields here: [link](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/3796#comment:3)

Comment: Of course - sorry for the delay. BTW, I have an another question about Vaadin, may be you can help me again. Thanks.